# Perl pattern match not working as expected

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to match values, which may be comma separated, using a regex. Basically, I want to return true if any value in the string does NOT have 3g or 3k starting in the 3rd position.

My test code is as follows:

```
my @a = ('in3g123456,dh3k123456,dhec110101','dhec110101,dhec123456','in3g123456,dh3k123456', 'c3kasdf', 'usdfusdufs3gsdf' );

foreach (@a) {
  print $_;
  say $_ =~ /(?:^|,)\w{2}[^(?:3G|3K)]/i ? " true" : " false";
}
```

This returns

```
in3g123456,dh3k123456,dhec110101 true
dhec110101,dhec123456 true
in3g123456,dh3k123456 false
c3kasdf false   <- whaaaaaaaat?
usdfusdufs3gsdf true
```

I don't understand why the 4th one is not true. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[^(?:3G|3K)]` reads as "any character but `(`, `?`, etc."

```
                      failed
                      v
        c3            kasdf
/(?:^|,)\w{2}[^(?:3G|3K)]/i
```

Use this:

```
/(?:^|,)\w{2}(?!3G|3K)/i
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/P2XsgN/1.

Comment: Or `(?!3[GK])`?

Comment: That's true but, well, the question is not about optimizing the regex, and the smallest change should show the most clear what was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

How about `/\b\w{2}(?!3g|3k)/i`.

`\b` matches the empty string at the beginning or end of a word. Slightly simpler equivalent to `(^|,)` in this situation.

`(?!foo)` is a zero-width negative lookahead assertion. So, matches the empty string as long as it's not followed by a substring that matches `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) the string first, instead of parsing everything with a regex. That is far more flexible and maintainable, and easier.

When processing the list of the extracted "values" you can match *any character* twice then your pattern, `/^..$patt/`. The module [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/~rehsack/List-MoreUtils-0.416/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm) is useful (and fast) for list manipulations, and its `notall` function is tailor-made for your condition.

```
use warnings 'all';
use strict;
use List::MoreUtils qw(notall);

my $file = '...';
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

while (<$fh>)
{
    my $res = notall { /^..(?:3k|3g)/ } split /,/;

    print "$_: " . ($res ? 'true' : 'false'), "\n";
}
```

I presume that you read from a file. If not, replace `while (<$fn>)` with `for (@strings)`.

The `notall` function returns true if any element of the list fails the condition.

The [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) by default uses `$_` so we only need the pattern. Here it is simply `,` but the pattern takes a regex so one can match separators flexibly. For example, this `/[,\s]+/` splits on any amount of `,` and/or whitespace. So `,,  ,` in a string is matched as a separator, as well as `,` or space(s).

When applied to the array with your strings the above prints

```
in3g123456,dh3k123456,dhec110101: true
dhec110101,dhec123456: true
in3g123456,dh3k123456: false
c3kasdf: true
usdfusdufs3gsdf: true
```

Comment: @Jim I updated this answer with output and more explanations

Answer (score 0):

You could use [**substr**](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) to get data at 3rd and 4th position and then compare it with `(3g|3k)`.

```
substr $_,2,2
```

---

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @a = ('in3g123456,dh3k123456,dhec110101','dhec110101,dhec123456','in3g123456,dh3k123456', 'c3kasdf', 'usdfusdufs3gsdf' );

foreach (@a) {
  my @inputs = split /,/,$_;
  my $flag = 0;
  foreach (@inputs){
    $flag = 1 unless ((substr $_,2,2) =~ /(3g|3k)/);
  }
  $flag ? print "$_: True\n" : print "$_: False\n";
}
```

Output:

```
in3g123456,dh3k123456,dhec110101: True
dhec110101,dhec123456: True
in3g123456,dh3k123456: False
c3kasdf: True
usdfusdufs3gsdf: True
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/VwTQNG)